# How to update NestJS Swagger module but use OpenAPI 2.0(Swagger)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs, openapi

We are making an API in Node.js/Typescript with NestJS framework. We use `@nestjs/swagger` package to make it conform to OpenAPI(formerly known as Swagger). It is inteneded to be used with `Azure/autorest` to generate client code.

Autorest supports OpenAPI 2.0 and not 3.0 yet. `@nestjs/swagger 3.*.*` implemented OpenAPI 2.0. When we update `@nestjs/swagger` to `4.*.*` it turns into OpenAPI 3.0. This doesn't fit our needs because we can't use Autorest anymore. On the other hand not updating the package means we might miss out security updates or not even be able to update the entire NestJS framework.

Is there any way to update `@nestjs/swagger` and stay with OpenAPI 2.0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately no. Internally, `@nestjs/swagger` v4 is specifically generating `OpenAPI 3.0 specification` specifically. There are two options right now while you wait for `autorest 3` to be released officially.

- Stay on `@nestjs/swagger` v3. As for `update the entire NestJS
  framework`, you don't have to worry about this because
  `@nestjs/swagger` is a pretty much *stand alone* package. Security
  issue regarding dependencies, I can see your concern is valid there.
- Try `autorest 3.beta` out to see if it's stable enough for you to
  use.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use the library

> api-spec-converter [enter link description here](https://github.com/LucyBot-Inc/api-spec-converter)

```js
const apiConverter = require('api-spec-converter');
const yaml = require('yaml');
const fs = require('fs');

apiConverter.convert(
  {
    sintax: 'yaml',
    order: 'openapi',
    from: 'openapi_3',
    to: 'swagger_2',
    source: './swagger-v3.json',
  },
  function(err, converted) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      console.log('Error converting file');
      return;
    }
    const yamlString = yaml.stringify(converted.spec);
    fs.writeFileSync('./swagger-v2.yaml', yamlString);

    console.log('Done!');
  },
);
```

Add a call script in the **package.json**:

> **"convert:swagger": "node ./swagger-converter.js"**

Please note that the source path is the one generated by NestJS.

Another point is that I'm generating the output in .**yaml**, but you can generate it in .**json** by just removing the syntax options and using **converter.stringify()** option